# How to I move text inside input text field?

Tags: css

I've created a 200x50px input text field. The text that is type in that input field automatically appears in the vertical center of that input field. How can I move it inside that text field? I tried to do stuff like padding-top:20px to move it down but that also makes the input field higher. And when I make that height smaller it cuts away the text at the bottom.

You can see a sample at: [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dENLJY)

I just added 1 input field:

```
<input placeholder="fill it in"></input>
```

And then used this css on it:

```
input {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

It's 200x50px high now, but I can't think of a way to move the filled in text down or up without making the input text area higher/smaller.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to do this, but if you just want to align the field value to the top or bottom of the field, you can do that by having padding-top but no padding bottom, or vice-versa.

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box` then you can apply padding

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me yet. Can you check out my codepen? In Safari the placeholder text is nicely entered and that placeholder green also fills the input area. In Chrome that placeholder text is vertically centered according to the top of that text and that smaller green area shows that. How can I make it both vertically centered? Just like the inputted text? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwpLYZ

Answer (score 0):

You can see my problem in this codepen: [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBRqNN)

The placeholder text and input text have different font sizes. In Chrome the place holder text is aligned to the top of the input text and in Safari it is aligned to the bottom of the input text.

```
input {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

::placeholder {
    /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

I'd like to have more control of how both the placeholder and input text are vertically positioned so they are positioned the same way in all browsers. Either at the vertical center, top or bottom of the fixed size input text field.